# Constraints while designing the Java generics

Tags: java, scala, generics

Java generics look quite different from those available in Scala, although both were designed by Martin Odersky. From my point of view, the design of generics in Java is worse, for instance:

- there is no possibility to specify variance
- one can get around the previous limitation by using wildcards, but this means the burden of specifying variance goes on the caller instead of the library designer
- one cannot use a type constructor in generics

What were the constraints in Java that forced Odersky to design this mechanism for generics instead of the more flexible one he devised for Scala? Was he just savvier a few years later or there were actual limitations due to Java?

Comment: IIRC, backwards compatibility was a major issue. If I get a few minutes, I'll look up an article I read on that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner noted, backwards compatibility was the single biggest constraint. And the resolution they chose was to keep backward compatibility by using *type erasure*, i.e. removing all generic type information during compilation. This means a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>` will become the same type at runtime (and the same as a pre-Java5 `List`). And it has a lot of negative consequences, including most of what you listed above.

#### Update

The constraints set by this are much tighter than one may naively think:

> What we require is that the same client code works with both the legacy and generic versions of a library. This means that the supplier and clients of a library can make completely independent choices about when to move from legacy to generic code. This is a much stronger requirement than backward compatibility; it is called migration compatibility or platform compatibility.
>
> Java implements generics via erasure, which ensures that legacy and generic versions usually generate identical class files, save for some auxiliary information about types. It is possible to replace a legacy class file by a generic class file without changing, or even recompiling, any client code; this is called binary compatibility.

(*Java Generics and Collections*, Chapter 5)

Binary compatibility is not always automatically guaranteed; section 8.4 of the same book details some cases where binary compatibility may break during genericizing legacy interfaces even if all general rules have been followed.

Another aspect of backward compatibility is adherence to a type system where not everything is an object. So in Java primitive types are out of scope for generics just as for collections, and you have boxing/unboxing to complicate life (whereas in Scala everything is an object).

A third legacy in Java is native arrays which just don't fit with generics:

- arrays are always reifiable types whereas generic types are not;
- arrays can store primitive types whereas (generic) collections can not;
- array subtyping is covariant, whereas generic subtyping is invariant;
- as a consequence, arrays are less type safe than generics, and one can argue that they should be declared obsolete in favour of generic collections and not used in new code.

All this means a lot more rules to adhere to, thus corner cases and compromises to make, limiting the power and simplicity of Java generics.

Several such decisions can be seen in retrospect as wrong, but there is no way back anymore, thus no possibility to fix them without breaking backward compatibility, which - rightly or not - has become a sort of holy cow in Java over the years. I conjecture that the story of Java generics most probably brought a lot of experience and food for thought for its own designers as well, and these experiences were surely reused during the design of Scala.

Comment: Thanks! There was a really good article I once read on this, going into much more detail. It was a while ago, and I can't seem to find it online anymore, as my bookmarks to it are dead (or it's moved)... :(

Comment: +1 "has a lot of negative consequences" is a very mild way to put it. I'd say "makes Java generics close to useless" :)

Comment: This does not answer the question. I know that generics had to be implemented with type erasure for backwards compatibility. Yet, the same holds for Scala generics, and still generics in Scala are more powerful - definitely not close to useless! So, what **other** constraints were there?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'd say the opposite: any *other* decision would have made generics close to useless. Backwards compatibility is a *hugely* important thing.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Michael on this. Without backward compatibility, we might have got "nicer" and "cleaner" generics in Java, just with a lot less actual users, since its adoption may have been much slower.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt It was not backward compatibility that drove the decision, but a desire to make it a compiler-only feature - essentially, a desire to let you run new code on old JVMs. Microsoft's success with adding generics to C# and VB that required significant changes to CLR is a hint that Java designers took a wrong route with Generics.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, what is it that enables you to "run new code on old JVMs" if not backward compatibility? :-o

Comment: @PéterTörök My understanding is that it is forward, not backward, compatibility. Backward compatibility lets a newer JVM run code produced by an older compiler; forward compatibility lets your older JVM accept code produced by a newer compiler.

Comment: @Andrea In addition to everything in this answer, the average Java programmer at that time was judged by the Java language committee to be nowhere near ready to handle the power of full higher-order parametric polymorphism, let alone full existential types and similar.  (Whether that judgement was correct or not is another question entirely.)  Extremely limited versions of each, in the forms of first-order reference-type-only invariant generics for the former and both wildcard generics and raw types for the latter, were as far as the committee was willing to go.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Even Microsoft felt the need stick with first-order generics only; as a result, LINQ syntax (in C# and VB.NET) and computation expressions (in F#) are forced to be fairly ad-hoc in how they get desugared.  Scala's `for` comprehensions suffer the exact same limitations, because they were there before higher-kinded types were added to the language.  In addition, because CLR generics are reified, Scala's .NET implementation has even more trouble interoperating with generic C# code than the original JVM one does with generic Java code.  (Look up, e.g., partial erasure for more.)

Comment: How would one implement generic collections without arrays? Most of the time they're not necessary, but there are specific use cases in which you have to use arrays rather than ArrayLists. One that comes to mind is a generic Set implementation I wrote for a previous employer which was more memory-efficient than HashSet and saved hundreds of megabytes of heap.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, agreed, there are specific use cases where you still need arrays. I believe though that "favour generic collections over arrays" is a perfect rule of thumb 99% of the time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, forward compatibility of the (old) JVM doesn't work without backward compatibility of the (new) compiler.